# OData - Nested $filter on collection in $expand

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf, odata

Similar to this example I'd like to filter a collection in "Order".
http://odata.github.io/WebApi/04-03-filter-in-expand/

Let's say we have following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

If I call following URI ***.../Customers?$expand=Orders($filter=Articles/Category eq 'Cookies')***, I get an error saying

> The parent value for a property access of a property 'Category' is not
>   a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

But I can use a construct like: ***.../Customers?$expand=Orders($filter=Articles/any(a:a/Category eq 'Cookies'))***

The problem with **any** or **all** is, that it is filtering the parant data, based on the children. Af "articles" with the "Category" are existing, it will return all articles. But I want to reduce the child-items to show only the articles of category "cookie".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use two nested different `any`, if I understand you, you want to filter all the `Articles` they are in `Cookies` category, I think you need something like :

```
.../Customers?$filter= Orders/any(o: o/Articles/any(p: p/Category eq 'Cookies'))
```

it will give you all `Customers` which have `Orders` if `Orders` have cookies `Articles` .

Regards.